# Dynamic instantiation in a sub-query is unsupported

Tags: database, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, subquery

I have a Car entity that contains a list of Price entities.
When retrieving the car from the database I can map it directly to my ViewCar DTO, but not so the list of prices.

Here is my ViewCar Dto:

```
public class ViewCar {

    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private Long uniqueId;

    private CarStatus status;

    private Double defaultPrice;

    private String location;

    private String city;

    List<ViewPrice> priceList;

    public ViewCar(Long id, String name, Long uniqueId, CarStatus status, Double defaultPrice, String location, String city, List<ViewPrice> priceList) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
        this.status = status;
        this.defaultPrice = defaultPrice;
        this.location = location;
        this.city = city;
        this.priceList = priceList;
    }
}
```

This is one implementation that I tried using EntityManager:

```
TypedQuery<ViewCar> query = entityManager.createQuery(
                "SELECT NEW com.example.core.car.dto.response.ViewCar(c.id, c.name, c.uniqueId, c.status, c.defaultPrice, c.location.name, c.city.name, " +
                        "(SELECT NEW com.example.core.price.dto.response.ViewPrice(p.value, p.from_date, p.to_date) FROM Price p WHERE p.car = c)) " +
                        "FROM Car c WHERE c.id = 21",
                ViewCar.class);
```

And also in the `JpaRepository<Car, Long>`

```
@Query("SELECT new com.example.core.car.dto.response.ViewCar"
            + "(c.id, c.name, c.uniqueId, c.status, c.defaultPrice, c.location.name, c.city.name, " +
            "(SELECT new com.example.core.price.dto.response.ViewPrice(p.value, p.from_date, p.to_date) " +
            "FROM Price p where p.car.id = ?1 )) FROM Car c WHERE c.id = ?1 AND c.deletedAt IS NULL")
    ViewCar findCarById2(@Param("id") Long id);
```

The error says: `Dynamic instantiation in a sub-query is unsupported`

I'm using Postgresql.

Comment: I've run into the same error. Not sure if it's really unsupported or there is a bug.